# Importing 10 Years of Media into the WP Database

Tags: database, uploads, media

I've been running the same website for 10 years now, and whenever I would create a news story, I would manually upload and store all my news images in a "news" folder via FTP and then manually write the HTML to call up each of those images (yes, it was always a pain). Each month has a folder within that news folder named MMYY (0613, for example). Well, now I want to actually use Wordpress's upload and insert features instead of doing everything manually. And with help from this wonderful website, someone was able to help me set Wordpress to upload all future images into the folder structure I've had for the past 10 years (/news/0613 instead of Wordpress's default wp-content/uploads/2013/06).

But now my problem is this: if I want to use all the other images and media stored in those 10 years of folders whenever I make a new news story, how do I pull them all into Wordpress? I could just insert the images manually by looking up their URLs, or insert them into Wordpress through the same way, but it would be nice to actually have them all stored in WP's database for easy look-up and inserting, all while using the existing files themselves in their stored locations (which, as I mentioned before, is now in the same folder structure that WP will be using to upload future images). I've looked everywhere and cannot find how to do this though or how to even approach something like this. I've looked through dozens of plugins as well. So I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terminology when I'm searching for my solution. Does anyone know what I can do or have tips for how I would even go about approaching this? Thank you! :)

Comment: This plugin »Add-From-Server« - http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/ - should help you to get the files into the database.